# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'path' in undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, cart

I am a new learner. I am trying to add cart feature using vue. Here is my view name Cart.vue for the cart.

```
<template>
    <div class="page-cart">
        <div class="columns is-multiline">
            <div class="column is-12">
                <h1 class="title">Cart</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="column is-12 box">
                <table class="table is-fullwidth" v-if="cartTotalLength">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <CartItem
                            v-for="item in cart.items"
                            v-bind:key="item.product.id"
                            v-bind:initialItem="item" />
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <p v-else>You don't have any products in your cart...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import CartItem from '@/components/CartItem.vue'
export default {
    name: 'Cart',
    components: {
        CartItem
    },
    data() {
        return {
            cart: {
                items: []
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.cart = this.$store.state.cart
    },
    computed: {
        cartTotalLength() {
            return this.cart.items.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
                return acc += curVal.quantity
            }, 0)
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the CartItem.vue component that I used:

```
<template>
    <tr>
        <td><router-link :to="item.product.get_absolute_url">{{ item.product.name }}</router-link></td>
        <td>Rs {{ item.product.price }}</td>
        <td>
            {{ item.quantity }}
        </td>
        <td>Rs {{ getItemTotal(item).toFixed(2) }}</td>
        <td><button class="delete"></button></td>
    </tr>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'CartItem',
    props: {
        initialItem: Object
    },
    data() {
        return {
            item: this.initialItem
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getItemTotal(item) {
            return item.quantity * item.product.price
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

I cannot see any product and the related values in the cart. I am getting this error -
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'path' in undefined.
I am unable to find out the mistake in my code. Please help me out. When I am removing the component from the cart.vue, then the error gets eliminated. But I need that component.